# Canvas Element stored in localStorage when I press "back" button

Tags: image, canvas, local-storage, webcam, data-url

In Angular JS (NodeJS back-end), I have a `<canvas></canvas>` that drawsImage after a user takes a photo with his/her webcam. After they submit the photo (moves onto next `location.href`), if the user hits the browser's "back" button, the image that was drawn onto canvas is still there even after I call `localStorage.clear()`.

What could be the issue here? Any help would be appreciated.